# Yodlee Add all Accounts from a Credit Card Account having hierarchy(One Parent account and Children accounts)

Tags: yodlee

I have a structured credit card account i.e. one main account and 4 others accounts linked to the Parent account. Is there a way to add separately those 4 accounts to my application using Yodlee Rest API. I've tried that with `"v1.0/jsonsdk/SiteAccountManagement/addSiteAccount1"` but it only gave me the main account. I would like to have the 4 accounts as well.
Can someone help ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be receiving all your accounts parent as well as child(if any) which is available at the bank website for Yodlee to scrape. While if this is not happening then I would suggest you to do this:

If you are already a customer then please use Yodlee Customer Care tool for raising a Service Request else you can please fill out the form mentioned [here](http://solutions.yodlee.com/APIDeveloperInquiryForm.html) to provide the details like siteAccountId & REST URL you are using for us to debug further.